# Strings being passed with ajax call are having spaces turned to '+'

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I am trying to use ajax to send a POST with a few strings as parameters. The strings sometimes need to have spaces. When the POST is received by the C# server side I am getting the same string but instead of spaces I get a + or %20. I just want to get whatever string was sent, as it was sent, whether it had spaces, +'s, or any % signs.

Comment: You really need to show your code, both client and server side.  You've either got a case of double escaping or escaping and not-escaping going on, but without your code it's impossible to say where.

Comment: can you provide some code !?

Comment: You probably need to do **urldecode** - check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

look into UnescapeDataString or UrlDecode to get the original value

Answer (score 0):

because the string is encoded use the following C# code to decode it and get back to original form

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(your string);
```